# Event Log Generator Tool?

Tags: windows-server-2008, event-log

Can someone provide lead to get Windows Event Log Generator tool for Windows 2008 R2 Server. As I need to fill the Log file for a specific application.

Early help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built-in [`eventcreate`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755240(WS.10).aspx) utility?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [link](http://www.hobbycode.com/projects/event-log/) , it has a tool which can generate almost all the event logs.

**From the website:**

> Event Log Generator is a simple application designed to create custom
>   Windows event logs Usage
>
> Simply run the executable.  All fields are required and cannot be left
>   blank.  Note that some event logs can only be viewed or modified by a
>   user with administrative permissions.  If you get a warning about this
>   when you run the application, you have a few options:
>
> Log out and log back in as the administrator
>   Give your account administrative permissions
>   Right click the application and select "run as", then select an administrative account to use.  This is the recommended method.
>
> Background
>
> During our SIEM implementation, it became necessary to write regular
>   expressions against collected logs, so they could be normalized and
>   correlated.  I created this application to generate logs so I could
>   test my regex's against them